# ORDER BY and GROUP BY doesn't work for me

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sql-order-by

I've a table called "Emps" contain 5 Cols (ID, Name, Gender, BirthDate, Profession)
and I need to

```
SELECT * 
FROM Emps 
ORDER BY ID 
GROUP BY Gender, BirthDate
```

but it doesn't work. I got this error

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ID group by Gender'

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since Gender and BirthDate are group by items,so they must be the select items.

```
select Gender ,BirthDate from Emps  group by Gender,BirthDate,id order by id
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Emps  GROUP BY Gender, BirthDate ORDER BY ID
```

ORDER BY should be after GROUP BY

Comment: err (Cannot group on fields selected with *)